# Laravel Passport No Error Appear If token is expired

Tags: php, laravel, api, postman, laravel-passport

I'm starting to learn the Laravel passport API. I tried to use my tokens and it works fine.When I revoke the specific token it works fine too, it shows the proper output that says

```
  {
    "message": "Unauthenticated"
  }
```

But when tried to use the token that is expired 1 day ago. It still authenticated which means doesn't do the same message when I put revoke on it.

I'm having the same problem in this thread:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/passport-not-erroring-on-expired-token?page=1

I'm thinking if there's another or tricky way how to check the expiration date of the specific token in the backend part. Recently I found an alternative way to validate the expired tokens. Which is the task scheduling of laravel. Where every minute the system will check if there's a token expired so that it will automatically update its revoke field as true. But I doubt this solution so that I'm still trying to find some other options.

Comment: did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem probably.
You must set the expiration time in `AuthServiceProvider` by adding         `Passport::tokensExpireIn();` to boot section and token won't be validated after this time but the problem is the token won't be revoked automatically and i don't get it why.
Maybe revoke is not for being set by passport and its only for us